# Call Methods from a list and store results

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, visual-studio

I want to create my own data validation system, let say

```
List<ValidationRule> list = new List<ValidationRule>();
list.Add(new ValidationRule(sometext, "Method regexTextValidation"));
list.Add(new ValidationRule(phonenumeber, "Method regexPhoneValidation"));
list.Add(new ValidationRule(somedate, "Method regexDateValidation"));
```

I want to store the results of each method and loop through them in order to see if something is wrong, if yes dosomething to the field in question.

**Edit :**

sometext is a string and the regexTextValidation is a method, i am trying some stuff and i guess i will go with a dictionary `Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, bool>> _DicValidationRules;` i will call it like this `_DicValidationRules.Add(1, new Tuple<string, bool>("some text", regexTextValidation("some text")));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use validation rules in WPF.  You generally reference them in XAML and define them for a binding.  Here is an example...

```
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                                <Binding Path="Value" NotifyOnValidationError="False" >
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <local:NumberValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

This particular validation rule verifies that the user typed a number greater than 0 in the text field.  You can have more than one validation rule and they all have to return a true validation result or an error is indicated.

```
public class NumberValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        double v = 0.0;
        if(double.TryParse(value as string, out v))
        {
            if(v <= 0.0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "number must be greater than 0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "entered value is not a number");
        }
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```